# separating a row python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, split, row

I have a table looks like this :

```
username     email                name         phone1     phone2
 1920      abc@gmail.com       TSteve/Nancy       a          b
```

I want this to be :

```
username     email            first_name     last_name    phone1     phone2
 1920      abc@gmail.com        Steve            T          a   
 1920-2                         Nancy            T                     b
```

this table is in csv format.

For summary:

1) split "name" column to "first_name" and "last_name" and takeout and move the very first letter "T" in this case to "last_name" and separate the row with two names "Steve" and "Nancy".  Steve/Nancy will be splitted based on "/" and remove the slash.

2) phone 1 stays but phone 2 will be moved to the next row. (I will merge phone1 and 2 later)

3) A new username one the second row will be the same number with "-2" at the end.

I spent 3 days trying several things but failed. It will be very helpful for me to study and learn if you guys can guide me through this steps.

Thank you

Comment: Please see [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [MCVE](/help/mcve) of your attempt.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need:

```
#get all columns without name
cols = df.columns.difference(['name']).tolist()
#create MultiIndex and split, reshape by stack
df = (df.set_index(cols)['name']
        .str.split('/',expand=True)
        .stack()
        .reset_index(name='first_name'))
#boolen mask for select only first or last new rows
m = df['level_4'].eq(0)
#remove column level_4
df = df.drop('level_4', axis=1)
#add last name for select first letter by condition, replace NaNs by forward fill
df['last_name'] = df['first_name'].str[0].where(m).ffill()
#get all letter without first
df['first_name'] = df['first_name'].mask(m, df['first_name'].str[1:])
#remove first all last values
df['email'] = df['email'].where(m, '')
df['phone1'] = df['phone1'].where(m, '')
df['phone2'] = df['phone2'].mask(m, '')
#add -2 for second rows
df['username'] = df['username'].where(m, df['username'].astype(str) + '-2')
print (df)
            email phone1 phone2 username first_name last_name
0   abc@gmail.com      a            1920      Steve         T
1                             b   1920-2      Nancy         T
2  abcd@gmail.com      a            1921      Steve         K
3                             b   1921-2      Nancy         K
```

Comment: Thank you, is it possible to remove T and K in front of the first names?

Comment: oops, I forget.

Comment: I am getting "NotImplementedError: > 1 ndim Categorical are not supported at this time" error in creating multiindex an split part.

Comment: It seems your names are categoricals. So try first step `df['name'] = df['name'].astype(str)`. If it does not work check `print(df.dtypes)` and all categoricals columns convert to strings. If still problem, let me know. Thanks.

Comment: thank you for your kind help. I tried your suggestion, but I am still having the same issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163912/discussion-between-yun-tae-hwang-and-jezrael).

Comment: Ok, what is `print(df.dtypes)`?